# Thought experiment of 0 times infinity and dimensions

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, thought-experiment

Take a cube at 1x1x1 and cut it in half. Take the 0.5x1x1 and cut it in half again. Eventually, you get an object that is 0x1x1. The object does not disappear. It instead now exists in the 2D world. Ok, now you might want to stop me and say it's not possible to infinitely cut like this. But a 3D object is at its core made up of a supposedly infinite number of 2D planes, so surely there is a way to go reverse and isolate just one plane. If anything, just see this from an abstract/theory perspective.

Now that we have a plane, we repeat the same process until we get an object that is 0x0x1. Now the object is in the 1D world. We repeat the same process to get an object that is 0x0x0. Now the object is in the 0D world. Let's call this 0D object a "dot".

The question then becomes: Is this "dot" nothing?

Assuming that an infinite number of this "dot" will result in a line, then would this inherently mean that 0 times infinity is something finite? Going on with the logic that an infinite number of lines make a plane and eventually a 3D object, then are we all made up of an infinite number of 0D "dot"s?

Comment: Well, in math you can divide by 2 as many times as you want and never get to 0. In physics, the rules change with scale. You really can't cut an atom in half as if it was a mathematical solid.

Comment: This seems to be more about math than physics. Integral calculus is all about adding up an infinite number of infinitesimal things to (often) get a finite result.

Comment: A point has zero volume. That does not mean a point is “nothing”. For example, it has a position, while “nothing” has no position.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with: cutting something like a cube in half, then cutting that half a cube in half, and cutting that in half, and so on- *an infinite number of times*- does *not* get you to zero.

Because of this, the rest of your argument does not make sense. See Charles Seife's book, *Zero: The Biography of A Dangerous Idea* for more explanation.